# Number theoretic functions and the distribution of primes

Tags: number-theory

Find a function $f(x)$ such that as $x \to \infty$ :

1. $f'(x)>0$
2. for every $\delta > 0$, $f(x)=o(x^\delta)$
3. $f(x)$ is not equal to $O(log^a(x))$

I'm not sure how to approach this problem, except that I believe I should be using some properties of the big and small O notation

Comment: You've not given much for Readers to appreciate what mathematical tools you have tried to bring to bear on this problem.  There are many ways you might supply some context for us to better understand how to help.  Merely posting the problem without more context is at best a curious omission and at worst suggests you have not yet tried to digest what the exercise is about.

Comment: Okay, I carefully formatted your post using $\LaTeX$, but you edited the Question and wiped that away.  You can review the edit history to see what happened.  What you added did little to clear up where you found this problem or what you tried.  The title appears wholly unconnected to the body of the post; neither the notion of number theoretic function nor of the distribution of primes is ever mentioned.

Comment: click on edit to see the latex I typed. If you write that $x^\delta = e^{\delta \log x}$ and $\log^a x = e^{a \log \log x}$ do you see any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

you want  $$  \log f < \delta \log x,  $$
$$   \log f > a \log \log x   $$

A  clean way is to just use geometric mean,
$$ \log f = \sqrt {\log x \;    \log \log x \;},  $$
$$f(x) = e^{\sqrt {\log x \;    \log \log x \;}}.  $$

Comment: hints.... ${}{}{}$